# Lambda in return statement gives two outputs but only one if print is not used

Tags: python, function, lambda

```
def x(n):
    return lambda a: print(a)
print(x(1)(2))
```

this outputs:
2
None

What is this None for?
I don't understand the flow here...

Comment: the inner lambda doesn't return anything

Comment: Replace `print(a)` with `return a` to understand.

Comment: ikr... lambda a: a*n only prints 2, i just dont get the flow of control in such functions, can you elaborate

Comment: any function that does not return anythin returns `None` implicitly. `print()` does not return anything so it returns `None`. You print the return of your lambda

Comment: yeah! got it, too dumb, i think i should sleep now, my brain clearly ain't working well XD

Comment: i was thinking that the lambda is being executed twice once with the parameter and once without it, that's why it is saying that a is None....XD anyways thanx for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is:

```
def x(n):
    return lambda a: a
print(x(1)(2))
```

When you do `return lambda a: print(a)`, you print `a` as well as return what `print()` returns which you print when you call the function. `print()` statement returns a `None`. See:

```
print(print(1))
# 1
# None
```